# How to combine two accuracy results?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, confidence-interval, standard-deviation, accuracy

If I am doing a machine learning experiment A and my accuracy lies in the interval of 0.8 +/-0.03 and I have a machine learning experiment B with an accuracy in the interval of 0.9 +/-0.1, how can I combine these two results into one? Are there any standard methods?

(The accuracy numbers I gave are for test sets that contain a sample of a whole population. However, these are two totally independent populations and samples.)

Comment: just to be sure you are referring to accuracy with respect to a classification problem correct?

Comment: Yes, these are classification experiments. Edited the question.

Comment: statistical ensemble? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ensemble_learning

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @Mitch. What I am looking for is actually how to combine the results for reporting. So, I do not want to combine the classifiers or classification tasks, but rather, is there a way to calculate an overall accuracy for A and B?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The combine accuracy depends on the proportions of A and B experiments.
If we call the proportions of A and B experiments $\tau_A$ and $\tau_B$,

the combine accuracy is:
$ Acc = 0.8\times\tau_A + 0.9\times\tau_B $,

and the combine accuracy uncertainty  is:
$\delta Acc = \sqrt{0.03^2\times\tau_A^2 + 0.1^2\times\tau_B^2}$.